# Renewing public ip address of an individual machine with cable modem

Tags: windows, networking, router, internet, cable-modem

I used to have broadband internet and on each machine I could connect via broadband using the same username and password (pppoe) and every machine could have a different public ip.

I now have cable internet and cannot seem to find a way to get a different public ip on each machine.

Does anyone know of a way to tunnel, or in some way allow to have a different public ip on each machine connected to the cable modem?

Comment: Contact your ISP to confirm their policies on the number of public IPs for your subscription. Many companies allow only one public IP (requiring you to use a router and a private IP scheme), or require you to purchase additional public IPs.

Comment: You could always use a proxy or something if the concern is showing whatever you are connecting to as each having a different IP address [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). Otherwise, for browsing the Internet, just put in "web proxies" into a Google search and there are tons of them you can use and go to [ShowMyIP](http://www.showmyip.gr/) so confirm those hide your public IP address. Maybe you simple just don't need to worry about it now since you're not using PPPOE.